# Question on the proof that underlying space $|K|$ is Hausdorff in Lemma 2.4 from Munkres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In Lemma 2.4 (Munkres), showing that underlying space $|K|$ is Hausdorff (given a simplicial complex $K$), if $x_0\neq x_1$ there's at least one vertex $v$ s.t. $t_v(x_0)\neq t_v(x_1)$. Can anyone justify that existence of such $v$? And also, can anyone give an example with picture (handwritten is OK) the open sets $\{x|t_v(x)>r\}$ and $\{x|t_v(x)<r\}$ for some $r$ between $t_v(x_0)$ and $t_v(x_1)$. I kinda difficult to grab the idea. Thanks very much for any help :)

Comment: What does the lemma say? And what does the notation $t_v$ stand for?

Comment: @manthanomen, the lemma says $|K|$ is Hausdorrf. $t_v(x)$ is the barycentric coordinate of $x$ with respect to $v$.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 11 questions in your first 8 days on this site. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/). (Although with the current rate of posting question, you will probably not run into these limits.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Thanks for editing my question and notify me about the limit. I haven't known there's a limit to post questions here. My lecturer just informed me about this site and I got excited in my early days of membership. This site has helped me alot in learning things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on Elements of Algebraic Topology, I see.

On page 4, top, he mentions that the barycentric coordinates are uniquely determined by $x$. Also, quite trivially, if two points have the same barycentric coordinates, then they are the same (because they are the same sum of weighted vertices). So different points $x_0 \neq x_1$ have at least one different barycentric coordinate, i.e. there is some vertex $v$ such that $t_v(x_0) \neq t_v(x_1)$. Then for some $r$ in-between these two reals, we have that $\{x: t_v(x) > r \} = (t_v)^{-1}[(r,\rightarrow)]$ is open, because $t_v$ is a continuous function on every simplex (by property (1) on the bottom of page 4), and inverse images of open sets are open under continuous functions. Likewise $\{x: t_v(x) < r \} = (t_v)^{-1}[(\leftarrow, r)]$ is open. These sets are disjoint and one of them contains $x_0$, the other $x_1$. No need to picture these sets, because elementary topology and set-theory gives us the required properties.

Comment: I know that this all makes sense if $x_0$ and $x_1$ both are in the same interior of a simplex. If so, then different point should have different barycentric coordinates. But proving Hausdorff just need two diferent points, can take any. How if $x_0$ is in the interior of a simplex spanned by $a_0, a_1, a_2$ and $x_1$ is in the interior of a simplex spanned by $a_1, a_2, a_3$. I can choose both having the same barycentric coordinates, yet they are different points. That's why I need justivication on the existance of such $v$ and the picture of the different open sets of those two points.

Comment: In your example the barycentric coordinate w.r.t. $a_0$ is always $0$ for the second point, so there we can almost always pick $v = a_0$, say.

Comment: Oh yeah. You're right :D Thanks.